# Tableau running slow/ Queries taking a long time

Tags: performance, calculated-field, tableau-desktop

To speed up processing time in tableau: Is it best to combine multiple calculated fields into one calculated field or best to have the equation broken out into pieces?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Both options are not related to optimization. However, it is a good practice to hide unused fields from the "tables" sidebar